# The Wikipedia module in Python 3.10 will not import

Tags: python, pip, wikipedia-api

I have a script for a personal assistant, which is still very rough around the edges, but an integral component is that the assistant can search and provide information from the internet. I wanted to use just the wikipedia module and not a complex web scraping process, and I've had great success with the wikipedia module before. I recently update to the 3.10 version of python and had to reinstall all my packages using pip3. When I tried to reinstall the wikipedia package, I get a very long error message(picture below). I tried to read the error but could not decipher it. Is my problem simply because the wikipedia module is not available for Python3.10, or is it something else? Is there any way that I can use the wikipedia module for this project?

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltnid.png)

Repeated x45

Comment: can you try removing it from the cache `pip3 cache remove wikipedia` and then reinstalling it

Comment: pip3 cache remove wikipedia worked, and one file was removed, but reinstalling throws the same error.

Comment: I tried installing the wikipedia module, and it worked normally, so it's definitely something else, Could u specify if you're running these commands on windows, wsl2, or linux?

Comment: I'm on macos in terminal with python3.10. Wikipedia worked fine with python 3.96, I thought it was the update but maybe not

Comment: Solved it-the problem was that setuptools had lapsed and needed to be manually reinstalled using pip3